# automatic login to website using codignitor through external link

Tags: php

I am trying to login to website through a link such as

```
https://websitename.com/some/link
```

which will be sent on mail, while user click on this link through mail.I want to make automatic login for that user so that user does not enter password and user name just click on the link and open the  page which I want to show to them.

How can I achieve this through php? please suggest.

Comment: you need to send what is called a unique user login token in that link and when a user clicks on it and lands on your site, GET token and verify through php and log the user in

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a **magic link**. what magic link does is your exact requirement. You will have to generate a magic link for a specific user, and optionally put an expiry for it, so that the link can't be misused.

If you care to use a framework like Laravel, here is an excellent [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/lets-kill-the-password-magic-login-links-to-the-rescue/)

The whole process of magic link generation and validationis not that difficult. Create a long [random](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) token and put it in in the db. When a link is hit, check the db for that token and if found (and still valid? based on the expiry) login the user and delete the token from the db if you don't want them to be reused.